# Azure Scheduler Job IP Address?

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I have an Azure Scheduler Job which calls a REST endpoint over https.

The REST API is locked down by IP address so it's currently (and understandably) failing. So I need to add the Scheduler Job IP address to the API firewall.

**The problem I have is I can't seem to find the IP address anywhere in the Azure Scheduler web interface.**

Am I missing something or is it not possible to get the IP address in same way you can for other Azure resources (web apps, worker roles etc)?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Azure Scheduler does not reserve static IP, so the IP will change from deployment to deployment as we ship new changes. You may consider Logic Apps, which also supports calling REST endpoint over HTTPs, and does have static IP. See this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-logic/app-service-logic-limits-and-config?toc=%2fazure%2flogic-apps%2ftoc.json#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the show but incase anyone else stumbles across this again, the IP addresses from the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) should get you what you need. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses) for details on getting the IPs. You can also add the IPs for the relevant Azure Data Centers to your allow list if necessary.